# RegEX for specific requirement

Tags: regex

I have one password text box which requirement is some thing like:

1. Should start with only Alphabets.
2. Should contain one numeric.
3. should contain one special character
4. not less than 10 character.

I have created this regEx :

`^.*[a-zA-Z](?=.*\d)(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=.{10,15}).*$`

but its taking first character as numeric and special character also, that should not to happen.

Comment: Why do you start it with skipping any number of any character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
^[a-zA-Z](?=.*\d)(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=.{9,}).*$
```

[See it](http://www.rubular.com/r/etJIfPOnaV)